# Why does my app react to taps outside a modal view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have an app that has a couple of embedded collection views inside of view containers in the root view. It also uses a modal view segue to open a preference setting view. I'm surprised to see that my app reacts to taps outside of the modal view. My non-iOS-specific understanding of "modal" views is that their primary reason for existence is to require a user to interact with them while ignoring any events outside of them.
Any thoughts on how I can stop my app from responding to taps outside the modal window would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[UIView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]` on the background view when the modal view is presented.